# (Beginner) How to deal with on scroll the Angular way

Tags: angularjs

I made this flowy menu in jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/krongbongtjong/5LeJh/
Easy peasy, but I want to do this the Angular way, but I don't know how to attack this.

If I do a directive

```
   <div stackables class="stackables">
```

How does that directive know what "stackable" elements to measure and modify?

If i instead do a directive on the child level

```
   <div stackable class="stackable">
```

How is it aware about it's sibling stackable's?
And, how can I avoid subscribing to more than 1 scroll event?

Very much a general beginner question. I hope it's not too vague for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi normally when creating your directive you will have access to the DOM element to which the directive is attached. It's the 2nd parameter of the link function and it looks like this :

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs)  //elem is the dom element
```

Now that you know that you can do whatever you want put the directive on the parent node or the children nodes. But in my opinion putting the directive on the parent node will be the "angular way" of doing it. To answer you question :

> How does that directive know what "stackable" elements to measure and
>   modify?

You will need to get familiar with the [transclude concept](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (look for transclude in the doc). Basically while using transclude the inner childs of your DOM element will be forwarded to the directive. Example :

```
// Template
<stackables>
  <li class="stackable">Item 1</li>
  <li class="stackable">Item 2</li>
  ...

// Directive
directive('stackables', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true, <- Here it is
  scope: {},
  template: '<ul class="stackables" ng-transclude></ul>', <- do not miss the ng-transclude here
  link: function (scope, elem) {
    //1. elem is the ul dom node
    //2. You can add an event listener from here
    //3. You can find the li dom with something like
    //elem.find('li');
    ...
```

Finally you should be able to attach your scroll event listener as usual to the `elem` of your directive and compute the size of your children elements with the help of the find function.